# Comparator as an anonymous sorter in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I am trying to sort a collection with a specific Comparator. Does it matter from a performance point of view to have a comparator defined in the sorted() clause of as a an anonumous instance, or it is better to create an instance once and just call compare method in the sorted() clause?

In essence, what is better:

1. ```
   myCollection.stream().sorted(
       new Comparator<String>(){
           public int compare(String a, String b){
               //code
           }
       })
   ```
2. ```
   Comparator<String> comp = new MyCustomComparator<>();
   myCollection.stream().sorted(comp::compare)
   ```

Note: neither syntax, nor comparing values matter - I want to know conceptually whether JVM is smart enough to initialize my anonymous comparator only once (case 1) and keep reusing just one method, or it will keep creating new instances (then I would choose case 2)

Comment: These two approach should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new instance of an anonymous class will be created every time the expression using `new` is evaluated.

- In your first example, a new one is created every time the statement runs where you are passing it to `sorted`.
- In your second example, a new one is created wherever the `comp` variable is being initialized. If `comp` is an instance member, then it gets created whenever the object that owns it is created. If `comp` is a local variable in a method, then it gets created every time the method is called.

A `static`, stateless and non-capturing `Comparator` is always going to be the most efficient way, because you can create it once and keep it forever. (See for example [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).)

That's not to say you shouldn't use another way.

In Java 8, you should prefer lambdas over anonymous classes. Non-capturing lambdas can be cached and only created once. For example, this program outputs `true`:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(comparator() == comparator());
    }

    static Comparator<String> comparator() {
        return (lhs, rhs) -> lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
}
```

(Example on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/MSBNVN).)

All that said, you shouldn't worry about creating a few small objects here in there in Java, because it's unavoidable and the garbage collector is optimized for it. The vast majority of the time, the "best" way to do something is also the most readable.

---

Note that you do not have to use a method reference in your second example. You can pass it to the method directly:

```
Comparator<String> comp = new MyCustomComparator<>();
myCollection.stream().sorted(comp)...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am actually really surprised by your separation of lambda from anonymous instances in terms of how they operate. I thought the main benefit of lambda is just being more compact. Apparently, I know nothing about lambdas.

Comment: Maybe you need to justify your sentence `A new instance of an anonymous class will be created every time the expression is evaluated.` This is simply not true. Easy to verify. Add a instance initializer block with `System.out.println("this = " + this)` to the anonymous class `new Comparator() ...` it will show that there is exactely **one** instance created for the stream.

Comment: @SubOptimal An anonymous class declaration is part of a class instance creation expression which creates a new instance when the expression is evaluated. (It's part of the expression using `new`.) I edited my answer if the meaning is actually unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime for both approach will be the same. This can be expressed as below :

For `1st scenario`, first JVM create instance of comparator with your custom code for compare method and allocated space for this object anonymously. So ultimately object is created and allocated memory without some pointing reference for user and once function call is over object is registered for GC.

For `2nd scenario`, JVM again created new instance of comparator with custom code and allocated space and also provide reference stored in separate variable so that this object can be used again but here object won't be collected by GC if same is used again in code anywhere else. So when GC runs for next time, it has to scan for references of variable and figure out whether it can be GCed or not.